# Inheritance and interfaces .NET

Tags: c#, oop

Quirky question:

Imagine that I have a base class called BaseFoo. I have an interface with some methods called IFoo. And I have tons of classes beneath BaseFoo.

If i implement the interface in BaseFoo, i dont need to implement in the inherited classes, correct?

Ok, but imagine that i have a generic function that will treat IFoo's. Do i need to explicitely declare that they implement IFoo?

Like this (pseudo-illustrational-code)

```
public class BaseFoo:IFoo;

public interface IFoo;
```

Should i do this?

```
public class AmbarFoo:BaseFoo,IFoo
```

or?

```
public class AmbarFoo:BaseFoo
```

What is the most correct way? Are the effects the same? If i test if AmbarFoo is a IFoo what will I get?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will behave the same way regardless. You'd only need to restate the interface name if you wanted to *reimplement* the interface with explicit interface implementation. An instance of `AmbarFoo` will indeed "say" that it implements `IFoo`.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the answer i needed.

Comment: I think Jon Skeet should skip questions like this one.

Comment: @Gordon: You're aware of the Jon Skeet Facts question on Meta, right?
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Answer (score 0):

> If i implement the interface in
>   BaseFoo, i dont need to implement in
>   the inherited classes, correct?

No, because BaseFoo will be forced to implement, and the child classes will inherit the implementation. They will all still be IFoos though.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it won't change anything.

However, look at the following one:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

public class FooBase
    : IFoo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FooBase");
    }
}

public sealed class SubFoo
    : FooBase//, IFoo
{
    public new void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SubFoo");
    }
}
```

Now run the following and comment out the "//, IFoo".

```
SubFoo foo = new SubFoo();

foo.Bar();
((IFoo) foo).Bar();
```

However, this is more theoretically.

Leave it away.